# How do you generate code with reactive_forms_generator in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do you generate code for a form using reactive_forms_generator build tool in flutter?

The instructions in the pub dev readme is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the build_runner package to generate code.

https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner

You should add the filename to be created as part/import.

Comment: Please can you show me an example, everything is greek to me?

Comment: I created this class below and ran this command  'flutter pub run build_runner build'. Nothing happened.

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';
import 'package:reactive_forms_annotations/reactive_forms_annotations.dart';


part 'jobdetails.gform.dart';

@Rf()
class JobDetails {
  
  String title;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  
  JobDetails({
     @RfControl(
      validators: const [requiredValidator],
    )  this.title,
     @RfControl(
      validators: const [requiredValidator],
    )  this.firstName,
     @RfControl(
      validators: const [requiredValidator],
    )  this.lastName,
      });
}

Comment: Maybe you will check to terminal error. İf don't have a any error, You must miss any annotation. You will compare your code and example.